# Facebook iFrame application - Get current userId before accepting permission

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm just wondering if it would be possible to get the id of the current user using javascript framework or something similar without them accepting permissions?

I'm using the facebooksdk for .net, I know I would be unable to get the id using the .net sdk but not sure how to do it using JavaScript any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean by "*accepting permission*" **authorizing your application** then **NO**, Facebook will not share the User ID before authorizing the application!

Comment: Can I ask then how do the facebook apps not let a user see an app page until they become a fan? I'm wanting to suggest they become fans but not enforce it but obviously want this show even if they haven't authorized the app as well. is this possible or have facebook stopped this in the new updates?

Comment: @MatthewDe'Loughry: Can you provide an example? like what page? and when you say app page...you mean app **profile** page and not the app canvas?

Comment: I'm unable to find an example at this time but similar to http://www.facebook.com/FoxNews?sk=app_23744633048 but i've seen Pages/Apps check if the users is a fan before content is show, however I dont want to enforce just suggest. I know alot of pages still use a static fbml page to accomplish this however I'm needing to use the new iframe method. If I managed to find an better example   I will post it.

Comment: @Matthew De'Loughry: ah this is a different matter, this is why I asked. Here this is called a Page Tab, you can read more about achieving this [here](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/determine-if-the-user-likes-fan-of-your-page-when-landing-on-your-page-tab/29/). It's in PHP, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is check if they have accepted permissions for your app before.  That way you know if you can get their Id with this code (i'm using 5.0.3)

```
public FacebookSession CurrentSession
    {
        get { return (new CanvasAuthorizer()).Session; }
    }

    [CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_about_me")]
    public bool UserHasApp()
    {
        if (CurrentSession == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }
```

If they have you app then you can get the id.  Look at the SDK example projects for how they get info from the user.